# Script merging two files

Tags: perl, hash

I'm fairly inexperienced with coding, but I often use Perl to merge files and match ID's and information between two files. I have just tried matching two files using a program I have used many times previously, but this time it's not working and I don't understand why.

Here is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw($damID $damF $damAHC $prog $hash1 %hash1 $info1 $ID $sire $dam $F $FB $AHC $FA $hash2 %hash2 $info2);


open (FILE1, "<damF.txt") || die "$!\n Couldn't open damF.txt\n";
my $N = 1;  
while (<FILE1>){
    chomp (my $line=$_);
    next if 1..$N==$.; 
    my ($damID, $damF, $damAHC, $prog) = split (/\t/, $line); 
        if ($prog){
            $hash1 -> {$prog} -> {info1} = "$damID\t$damF\t$damAHC"; 
        }


    open (FILE2, "<whole pedigree_F.txt") || die "$!\n whole pedigree_F.txt \n";
    open (Output, ">Output.txt")||die "Can't Open Output file";

    while (<FILE2>){
        chomp (my $line=$_);
        next if 1..$N==$.; 
        my ($ID, $sire, $dam, $F, $FB, $AHC, $FA) = split (/\t/, $line); 
        if ($ID){
            $hash2 -> {$ID} -> {info2} = "$F\t$AHC"; 
        }
          if ($ID && ($hash1->{$prog})){ 
            $info1 = $hash1 -> {$prog} -> {info1};
            $info2 = $hash2 -> {$ID} -> {info2};
            print "$ID\t$info2\t$info1\n";
        }
    }
}


close(FILE1);

close FILE2;
close Output;

print "Done!\n";
```

and these snippets from the two input file formats:

**File 1:**

```
501093  0   0   3162
2958    0   0   3163
1895    0   0   3164
1382    0   0   3165
2869    0   0   3166
2361    0   0   3167
754     0   0   3168
3163    0   0   3169
```

**File 2:**

```
49327   20543   49325   0.077   0.4899  0.808   0.0484
49328   15247   49326   0.0755  0.5232  0.8972  0.0499
49329   27823   49327   0.0834  0.5138  0.8738  0.0541
```

I want to match the values from `column 4 in file 1`, with `column 1 in file 2`.

Then I also want to print the matching values from `columns 2 and 3 in file 1` and `columns 3 and 5 in file 2`.

Also, it is probably worth mentioning there are about **500000** entries on each file.

This is the output I am getting:

```
11476   0.0362  0.3237  501093  0   0
11477   0.0673  0.4768  501093  0   0
11478   0.0443  0.2619  501093  0   0
```

Note that it isn’t looping through the first hash that I created.

Comment: What is going wrong? Is it possible the space in the second file name is throwing things off? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Please add your desired output

Comment: The first hash doesn't seem to be looping through. It almost seems like use vars qw(); isn't working on the file

Answer (score 1):

Create two tables in SQLite. Load the TSVs into them. Do a SQL join. It will be simpler and faster.

[Refer to this answer about how to load data into SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562196/very-huge-assosiative-array-in-perl/42563133#42563133). In your case you want `.mode tabs`.

```
sqlite> create table file1 ( col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int );
sqlite> create table file2 ( col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 numeric, col5 numeric, col6 numeric, col7 numeric );
sqlite> .mode tabs
sqlite> .import /path/to/file1 file1
sqlite> .import /path/to/file2 file2
```

There's any number of ways to improve those tables, but I don't know what your data is. Use better names in your own. You'll also want to declare things like primary and foreign keys as well as [indexes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm) to speed things up.

Now you have your data in an easy to manipulate format using a well known query language, not a bunch of custom code.

> *I want to match the values from column 4 in file 1, with column 1 in file 2.*
>
> *Then I also want to print the matching values from columns 2 and 3 in file 1 and columns 3 and 5 in file 2.*

You can do this with a [SQL join](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) between the two tables.

```
select file1.col2, file1.col3, file2.col3, file2.col5
from file1
join file2 on file1.col4 = file2.col1
```