# Efficiently reading a text file in Cython

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

I have a very large text file (58 million lines) that I want to process using Cython. It looks like this:

```
 262.000    1.000        2.2900
 263.000    1.000       -2.1562
 264.000    1.000       -1.7201
 265.000    1.000        1.1220
 266.000    1.000       -0.0108
 267.000    1.000        0.4371
 268.000    1.000       -0.1519
 269.000    1.000        0.1389
```

And so on. I need to go line-by-line and get the three values; the first two should be converted to integers, then the last one remains a float. I use a dictionary (c++ map) to convert the first two numbers to two new numbers, then use those new numbers as indices to a 2D array and at that position, add the absolute value of the third value.

By far my biggest bottleneck is just processing the data. The fastest algorithm that I have been able to write uses Pandas to read in the file and converts it to a Numpy array, but this still takes about 30 seconds, with the whole script taking about 35 seconds.

The code for this implementation is below:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def GetInteractionMatrices(self, path: str) -> np.ndarray:
    cdef:
        np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] res_res
        np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] data
        int length
        int i
        int atomResidue_i
        int atomResidue_j
        double value

    res_res = np.zeros((self.numResidues,self.numResidues), dtype=np.float64)
            
    data = np.abs(pd.read_csv(path, sep="\s+", header=None, skiprows=1).to_numpy())
    length = data.shape[0]

    # Needed to ensure the data is contigious in memory
    res_res = res_res.copy(order='C')
    data = data.copy(order='C')
    
    cdef np.float64_t[:, ::1] res_resView = res_res
    cdef double[:, ::1] dataView = data
    
    for i in range(length):
        atomResidue_i = self.atomResidueDict[<int>dataView[i, 0]]
        atomResidue_j = self.atomResidueDict[<int>dataView[i, 1]]
        
        if atomResidue_i == atomResidue_j: continue
        
        value = dataView[i, 2]

        res_resView[atomResidue_i, atomResidue_j] += value

    return res_res
```

But some more consideration of the algorithm led to me realize that I don't really need to read the data in memory at all, and I can just process it as a data stream. However, my best implementation of this is about 2x slower than the above code, taking about 55 seconds.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def GetInteractionMatrices(self, path: str) -> np.ndarray:
    cdef:
        np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] res_res
        np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] dataTemp
        int i
        int atomResidue_i
        int atomResidue_j
        double value

        FILE* p
        char *token
        char line[50]
        char path_c[100]

    res_res = np.zeros((self.numResidues,self.numResidues), dtype=np.float64)
    dataTemp = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float64)
    
    # Needed to ensure the data is contigious in memory
    res_res = res_res.copy(order='C')

    cdef np.float64_t[:, ::1] res_resView = res_res
    cdef double[:] dataTempView = dataTemp
    
    strncpy(path_c, path.encode('utf-8'), sizeof(path_c)-1)
    path_c[sizeof(path_c)-1] = b'\0'
    p = fopen(<char*>path_c, "r")
    if p is NULL:
        PyErr_SetFromErrnoWithFilenameObject(OSError, <char*>path_c)
    fseek(p, 0, SEEK_SET)  # Move to the beginning of the file

    while fgets(line, 50, p) != NULL:
        i=0
        token = strtok(line, ' ')
        while token != NULL and i < 3:
            dataTempView[i] = atof(token)
            token = strtok(NULL, ' ')
            i += 1

        atomResidue_i = self.atomResidueDict[<int>dataTempView[0]]
        atomResidue_j = self.atomResidueDict[<int>dataTempView[1]]
        
        if atomResidue_i == atomResidue_j: continue

        res_resView[atomResidue_i, atomResidue_j] += np.abs(dataTempView[2])

    return res_res
```

Surprising, using numpy to get the absolute value alone adds 30 additional seconds to the process, which I think is probably the only advantage of reading the data into memory.

I still think this has the potential to be faster, I suspect an additional inefficiency is with the nested while loops and splitting the string based on spaces, though at this point I'm not sure how I could further optimize it.

**-----EDIT 1-----**

I took some suggestions and made the following changes:

- Replaced `np.abs` with `abs` which Cython optimizes
- Converted my dictionary to a Numpy array

This managed to bring the time down from 55 seconds to only 14!

I then tried to implement my own parsing function using knowledge of the specific format of the file, but I seem to have made it worse. If anyone would like to take a look at it, I'd love some feedback on it:

```
cdef ParseLine(bytes line):
cdef:
    int i = 0
    int num1 = 0
    int num2 = 0
    double num3 = 0

# Ignore leading spaces
while line[i] == 32:
    i += 1

# Build first number
while 48 <= line[i] <= 57:
    num1 = line[i] - 48 + num1 * 10
    i += 1

# Ignore decimal point and any trailing zeros
i += 4

# Ignore spaces
while line[i] == 32:
    i += 1

# Build second number
while 48 <= line[i] <= 57:
    num2 = line[i] - 48 + num2 * 10
    i += 1

# Ignore decimal point and any trailing zeros
i += 4

# Ignore spaces or sign (we would've taken abs anyway)
while line[i] == 32 or line[i] == 45:
    i += 1

# Build third number
while 48 <= line[i] <= 57:
    num3 = line[i] - 48 + num3 * 10
    i += 1

# Ignore decimal point

num3 =  num3 + (line[i+1] - 48) * 0.1
num3 =  num3 + (line[i+2] - 48) * 0.01
num3 =  num3 + (line[i+3] - 48) * 0.001
num3 =  num3 + (line[i+4] - 48) * 0.0001

return num1, num2, num3
```

This feels inefficient, but from what I've been able to find, this is basically how `atoi` and `atof` are implemented. Though this is about 50 seconds slower, so there must be some optimizations somewhere.

**-----EDIT 2-----**

If anyone else is in the position, changing the function signature from `cdef ParseLine(bytes line)` to `cdef (int, int, double) ParseLine(char* line)` (note `char*` rather than `bytes`) sped up the code from ~60 seconds to ~3 seconds! I think it's because `bytes` is a Python object which has a large access overhead, and `char*` is a C object, which is optimized by Cython.

Comment: Numpy calls are not optimized by Cython as opposed to Numba. This means each call will be very expensive (each call to `np.abs` is done by CPython and not Cython and you pay the Numpy internal overhead). You should write your own version of `np.abs` which is fortunately straightforward to implement.

Comment: I wonder if the dictionary lookups in the loop are a slow part. Any chance those could be changed into arrays since they have integer indices?

Comment: Moreover, parsing is also notoriously slow, especially floating point numbers. You have 2 options: doing that in parallel, or optimize the conversion by writing a *specialized* implementation fitting with your input format (assuming input numbers cannot be any possible number).

Comment: Using the builtin `abs` ought to be faster than the NumPy one, because there's a Cython optimization for that which calls a C library function directly, according to https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1255

Comment: These are great suggestions. @JérômeRichard, what do you mean by writing a specialized conversion implementation? Given that each row only has three numbers to parse I'm not sure if it's worth the overhead to parallelize it, unless I've misunderstood you.

Comment: Regarding the specialized conversion, the thing is to write a lower-level code not using the libc but basic condition and operations. This works well if you know the format is rather fixed like parsing 3 digits then a dot and then 3 digits. One fast way to do that is to parse 2 integers `A` and `B` and then do `A + B * 0.001` which is just one fast FMA and 2 int to FP number conversions as opposed to many of them in the libc. Parsing space can also be faster with a simple while loop skipping only space. This is less flexible / more specialized but generally significantly faster.

Comment: For parallism, this is not trivial to do but the idea is to split the file in chunks and then parse the blocks in parallel. Once decoded, the chunks are computed serially because `res_resView[atomResidue_i, atomResidue_j] += np.abs(dataTempView[2])` can certainly not be parallelized. IDK if the dict access can. It depends of the exact type of the variables (CPython objects needs to be protected by the GIL preventing any parallelism). The first thing to do is to check the generated code by Cython and *profile* it (so to do the most useful optimizations).

Comment: "*with the whole script taking about 35 seconds*" If you only have to process the file once, you're done! If you have to process the file more than once, you probably want to translate it into a more efficient format. That depends on what you plan to do with the data, but a SQL database (which usually have its own CSV import functions) is a good generic choice. See [Manipulation performance of Sqlite vs CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40696615/14660).